# Footnote placement -- inside or outside terminal quote?

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, ap-style

When you are referencing information in the footnote, is it customary to put the footnote number inside the quote or outside?

For instance is it:

> "The pink pig."<sup>1</sup>

or:

> "The pink pig.<sup>1</sup>"

Comment: Superscript is `<sup> 1 </sup>` .

Comment: Outside. It is not part of the quote.

Comment: Would you care to choose an answer as acceptable, or comment on why the answers don't meet your needs?

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to APA style and you want to cite a quote you're using, then you don't use numbered lists, instead you use authors and page numbers to reference the specific quote.
If you want to reference specific content, without a quote, that adds to the material you've described, then I'd say that the footnote ID, <sup>1</sup>, would follow your text.

- [APA Citations](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/02/)
- [APA Footnotes](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/04/)